# Regex validation on email and password is not working

Tags: angular8

The validation is not working when I submit the code.

```
public loginForm: FormGroup;
public emailRegEx =  '^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$';
public passwordRegEx = '^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}$';

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
     this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
         email: new FormControl("", [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.emailRegEx)]),
         password: new FormControl("", [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.passwordRegEx)]),
```

Comment: Does the validation not allow valid credentials, or does it allow invalid credentials, or does it give some error message?

Comment: What are your actual results and what are your expected results.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - it does not give any error and accepting whatever i am giving in the text box. i want that it should show some error if user type suppose 10 characters in password or @ is missing in emal

Answer (score 0):

You can use follow simple regex

```
email: `/[^@]+@[^\.]+\..+/g`
```

and `password` regex you can follow one of these regexes below.

```
(?=.*[a-z]): for The string must contain at least 1 lowercase alphabetical character

(?=.*[A-Z]): The string must contain at least 1 uppercase alphabetical character

(?=.*[0-9]): The string must contain at least 1 numeric character

(?=.[!@#\$%\^&]): The string must contain at least one special character, but we are escaping reserved RegEx characters to avoid conflict

 ^(((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))): The string must contain at least 1 lowercase alphabetical and uppercase or at least 1 lowercase alphabetical and number
```